Windows Server 2025: Formatting a storage space volume with ReFs fails
I have a problem in a Windows Server 2025 VM when creating a volume/drive with the ReFS file system. The drives are passed through to the VM via HBA. They are 2 SATA WD hard disks with 8TB and 12TB. According to Hard Disk Sentinel, they are both error-free.
Both disks are part of a storage pool on which a virtual disk was created that uses the entire pool. Now I want to create a local volume with a drive letter. However, an error message appears when formatting:
Failed to format volume - Invalid Parameter Activity ID: {....}

The problem only occurs when formatting with ReFS and not with NTFS.
The event viewer shows:
An error has occurred during method execution.
Class: MSFT_Volume
Method: Format
Error Code: 5
Error Message: Invalid Parameter
Activity ID: {5818e172-3cd2-0003-34e9-1858d23cdb01}

What I have already tried:

NTFS instead of ReFS works.

The error occurs regardless of whether I do a quick format or a complete format.

sfc /scannow is error-free

I can't find anything suspicious in the Event Viewer, but I don't know exactly where the format errors are.

The same error occurs when I try to create the volume in Computer Management.

I also have other hard disks on the HBA that are assigned to a different storage pool.

Formatting on commandline gives same error.
C:\Users\Administrator>format T: /FS:ReFS /V:test /Q
The type of the file system is REFS.
WARNING, ALL DATA ON NON-REMOVABLE DISK
DRIVE T: WILL BE LOST!
Proceed with Format (Y/N)? Y
QuickFormatting 7,0 TB
Creating file system structures.
Format complete.
7.0 TB total disk space.
7.0 TB are available.
Format failed.
PS C:\Windows\System32> Format-Volume -FileSystem ReFS -Force -DriveLetter T
Format-Volume: Invalid Parameter
Activity ID: {5818e172-3cd2-0003-34e9-1858d23cdb01

I tried different HDD, same issue


My expectation is that I can format the volume with ReFS without any errors.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
